# SSSD Authentication to Windows Domain without @domain.com everywhere

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, ubuntu-14.04, sssd

We're trialling using a Ubuntu 14.04 desktop environment for a few of our developers and I've hooked the machines into the domain with SSSD. This has been working fine. However the system recognises the domain users as user@DOMAIN.COM, so 'ls -l' output is quite messy. It also turns out they have some test scripts that have username hardcoded and so this @DOMAIN.COM breaks them.

Is there a way to make SSSD show the domain users as just 'username' instead of 'username@DOMAIN.COM'? If not, is there a system that will allow me to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 'default_domain_suffix' answer is valid for users from a trusted domain (i.e. IPA-AD trust is in place).

However, if your setup only has one domain, then removing "use_fully_qualified_names=True" from the config is an easier way.

Comment: Whilst I didn't have 'use_fully_qualified_names' enabled. This put me on my way to working out how to completely eliminate the 'SMALLBUSINESS.LAN' component.

Comment: Correction; this did entirely do what I needed. There was just some strange things going on with my test system after all the options I'd changed.

Comment: @jhrozek I have no `sssd.conf` file. Is there another way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

you need to add default_domain_suffix  to your sssd.conf file. Bear in mind it only works under [sssd] section.

e.g.:

```
[sssd]
domains = YOURDOMAIN
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
default_domain_suffix = YOURDOMAIN
```