# Changing login-formats for Linux and Active Directory

Tags: centos, active-directory, kerberos

On CentOS, I run `realm list` and see `login-formats: %U@mydomain.local`

I'd like to change `login-formats: %U@mydomain.local` to `login-formats: %U`

How would I go about doing this? I'm assuming there is a `.conf` file, I've checked `sssd.conf` and `krb5.conf` and even checked `man` on those files.

What I'm trying to do is allow an active directory user to login to the linux box using `username@host` instead of `username@domain@host`. Currently `username@domain@host` works fine but not `username@host`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/648515/sssd-authentication-to-windows-domain-without-domain-com-everywhere

Answer (score 9):

This was kind of confusing to figure out for me because there was no reference to the term login-formats anywhere in any documentation.

In /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

add a line in the domain section to include this:

```
    [domain/contoso.com]
    ...
    use_fully_qualified_names = False
    ...
```

then restart sssd.

Comment: Good call - this works perfectly. Format is now simply %U which works great with pam_mount

Answer (score 1):

i did this and working as expected as like `login-formats: %U`

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/use_fully_qualified_names = True/use_fully_qualified_names = False/g' /etc/sssd/sssd.conf

sudo systemctl restart sssd.service

sudo systemctl status sssd.service
```